# Azure DevOps Pipelines- incorrect value in variables declaration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the CI/CD capabilities of Azure DevOps in order to build our micro-services.

One of the tasks I have inside the pipeline is a `Bash` Task that assign & execute variable declaration for further use in the same job.

When trying to gather the variable after the declaration I'm getting the output `{`.

The file I'm trying to read its data assigned to a variable is a JSON file, contains a JSON formatted data.

The file called pipeline_1.json, just to make sure that its inside the folder I need before trying to read it.
[image: ls command]

That is the command that takes the output to the variable.
[image: Variable assign]

And finally the output.
[image: Output of command]

My insight was its printing only the first line of the JSON file because its formatted but when tried to format it as simple text it gives the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it seems that you need to get the value in the Json file.

You can try to use the following bash script:

For example:

Json file:

```
{
  "AA": {
    "BB": "TEST",
    "CC": "XXX"
  }
}
```

Bash script:

```
token1=($(jq -r '.AA.BB' pipeline_1.json))

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token1;]$token1"
```

Then you can get the correct value in the json file.

Comment: If I want to get the entire JSON file as value? its possible with that method?

Comment: variable only supports single-line string.  This is the reason why it only get `{`  in your situation .I'm afraid this method is not suitable. Because it can't keep the json format.

Comment: So I need to format it as clear text first and if later on to use it as JSON format I'll need to format it on runtime?

Comment: Yes. You need to change the value as string  to  save the value to variable, then you can convert it back to json when you use it